# A difficult inequality in a triangle with a weird equality case.

Tags: geometry, inequality, area

In $\Delta ABC,$ let $BC = a, CA = b,$ $AB = c$ and $\Delta$ be its area. Suppose that $M, N, $and $P$ are points on the sides $BC,$ $CA,$ and $AB$ respectively. Prove that $$ab\cdot MN^2+ bc\cdot NP^2+ ca\cdot PM^2 \geq 4\Delta^2.$$ And equality holds iff $AM, BN$ and $CP$ are the Gergonne cevians of $\Delta ABC.$

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: A natural way to start would be by denoting the Gergonne point as $G$ and then expand out via: 
$$MN^2 = (\vec{MG} + \vec{GN},\vec{MG} + \vec{GN} )^2 = |MG|^2 + |GN|^2 + 2(\vec{MG}, \vec{GN})$$

Answer (score 1):

*Here is a proof using complex numbers*.

By Heron's formula, we have
$$\Delta = \sqrt{s(s - a)(s - b)(s - c)}$$
where $s = (a + b + c)/2$.

Let $B = 0, C = a$ and $A = A_1 + \mathrm{i}A_2$ where $A_1, A_2$ are both reals, and $\mathrm{i} = \sqrt{-1}$.
WLOG, assume that $A_2 > 0$.

From $|A - B| = c$ and $|A - C| = b$, we have
$$A_1 = \frac{a^2 + c^2 - b^2}{2a}, \quad A_2 = \frac{2\Delta}{a}.$$

There exist real numbers $u, v, w$ such that
\begin{align*}
 M &= u B + (1 - u)C, \\
 N &= vC + (1 - v)A , \\
 P &= wA + (1 - w)B .
\end{align*}

We need to prove that
$$ab |M - N|^2 + bc |N - P|^2 + ca|P - M|^2 \ge 4\Delta^2$$
or
\begin{align*}
   &\left( 4\,{a}^{3}b+4\,{a}^{3}c \right) {u}^{2}
   + \left( 4\,a{b}^{3}+4\,{b}^{3}c \right) {v}^{2}
    + \left( 4\,a{c}^
   {3}+4\,b{c}^{3} \right) {w}^{2}\\
   & + \left( 4\,{a}^{3}b+4
  \,a{b}^{3}-4\,b{c}^{2}a \right) uv
    +
  \left( -4\,{a}^{2}bc+4\,{b}^{3}c+4\,b{c}^{3} \right) vw\\
  &+ \left( 4\,{a}^{3}c-4\,a{b}^{2}c+4
  \,a{c}^{3} \right) uw\\
  & + \left( -4\,{a}^{3}b-8\,{a}^{3}c-4\,a{b}^{3}+4\,
  b{c}^{2}a \right) u
+ \left( 4\,{a
  }^{2}bc-8\,a{b}^{3}-4\,{b}^{3}c-4\,b{c}^{3} \right) v\\
&  + \left( -4\,{a}^{3}c+4\,a{b}^{2}c-4\,a
  {c}^{3}-8\,b{c}^{3} \right) w\\
  & +{a}^{4}+4\,{a}^{3}c-2\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}-2
  \,{a}^{2}{c}^{2}+4\,a{b}^{3}+{b}^{4}-2\,{b}^{2}{c}^{2}+4\,b{c}^{3}+{c}
  ^{4}\\
 \ge{}& 0.\tag{1}
\end{align*}

(1) is written as
$$p_1 u^2 + p_2u + p_3 \ge 0 \tag{2}$$
where
\begin{align*}
 p_1 &= 4\,{a}^{3}b+4\,{a}^{3}c, \\
 p_2 &= 4\,{a}^{3}bv+4\,{a}^{3}cw+4\,a{b}^{3}v-4\,a{b}^{2}cw-4\,ab{c}^{2}v+4\,
 a{c}^{3}w\\
 &\qquad -4\,{a}^{3}b-8\,{a}^{3}c-4\,a{b}^{3}+4\,ab{c}^{2},\\
 p_3 &= -4\,{a}^{2}bcvw+4\,a{b}^{3}{v}^{2}+4\,a{c}^{3}{w}^{2}+4\,{b}^{3}c{v}^{
  2}+4\,{b}^{3}cvw\\
 &\qquad +4\,b{c}^{3}vw+4\,b{c}^{3}{w}^{2}-4\,{a}^{3}cw+4\,{a}^
 {2}bcv-8\,a{b}^{3}v\\
 &\qquad +4\,a{b}^{2}cw-4\,a{c}^{3}w-4\,{b}^{3}cv-4\,b{c}^{3
 }v-8\,b{c}^{3}w+{a}^{4}\\
&\qquad +4\,{a}^{3}c-2\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}-2\,{a}^{2}{c}^{2
 }+4\,a{b}^{3}+{b}^{4}-2\,{b}^{2}{c}^{2}+4\,b{c}^{3}+{c}^{4}.
\end{align*}

Since $p_1 > 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$4p_1 p_3 - p_2^2 \ge 0$$
or
$$16a^2(a+b+c)(r_1v^2 + r_2v + r_3) \ge 0 \tag{3}$$
where
\begin{align*}
 r_1 &= -{a}^{3}{b}^{2}+{a}^{2}{b}^{3}+{a}^{2}{b}^{2}c+a{b}^{4}+2\,a{b}^{3}c+a
 {b}^{2}{c}^{2}-{b}^{5}+{b}^{4}c+{b}^{3}{c}^{2}-{b}^{2}{c}^{3},\\
 r_2 &= -2\,{a}^{3}bcw-2\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}cw-2\,{a}^{2}b{c}^{2}w+2\,a{b}^{3}cw+4
 \,a{b}^{2}{c}^{2}w+2\,ab{c}^{3}w\\
 &\qquad +2\,{b}^{4}cw-2\,{b}^{3}{c}^{2}w-2\,{b
 }^{2}{c}^{3}w+2\,b{c}^{4}w+2\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}+4\,{a}^{3}bc-2\,{a}^{2}{b
 }^{3}\\
&\qquad -2\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}c-2\,a{b}^{4}-2\,a{b}^{2}{c}^{2}-4\,ab{c}^{3}+2
 \,{b}^{5}-2\,{b}^{4}c-2\,{b}^{3}{c}^{2}+2\,{b}^{2}{c}^{3}, \\
 r_3 &= -{a}^{3}{c}^{2}{w}^{2}+{a}^{2}b{c}^{2}{w}^{2}+{a}^{2}{c}^{3}{w}^{2}+a{
  b}^{2}{c}^{2}{w}^{2}+2\,ab{c}^{3}{w}^{2}+a{c}^{4}{w}^{2}-{b}^{3}{c}^{2
 }{w}^{2}\\
&\qquad +{b}^{2}{c}^{3}{w}^{2}+b{c}^{4}{w}^{2}-{c}^{5}{w}^{2}-2\,{a}^{
  3}bcw+2\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}cw+2\,{a}^{2}b{c}^{2}w+2\,a{b}^{3}cw\\
 &\qquad-4\,a{b}^{2
 }{c}^{2}w -6\,ab{c}^{3}w-2\,{b}^{4}cw+2\,{b}^{3}{c}^{2}w+2\,{b}^{2}{c}^
 {3}w-2\,b{c}^{4}w+{a}^{4}b\\
 &\qquad +{a}^{4}c-2\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}-2\,{a}^{3}bc-{a}
 ^{3}{c}^{2}+2\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}c+{a}^{2}b{c}^{2}-{a}^{2}{c}^{3}+2\,a{b}^
 {4}-2\,a{b}^{3}c\\
 &\qquad -a{b}^{2}{c}^{2}+4\,ab{c}^{3} +a{c}^{4}-{b}^{5}+{b}^{4}
 c+{b}^{3}{c}^{2}-{b}^{2}{c}^{3}.
\end{align*}

We have $4r_1r_3 - r_2^2 = 64(b+c))b^2a(-2cw+a-b+c)^2\Delta^2 \ge 0$.

Also, we have
$$r_1 = 4(y+z)^2(x^2y+x^2z+xy^2+4xyz+xz^2+y^2z+yz^2) > 0$$
where $x = \frac{c + a - b}{2}, 
y = \frac{a + b - c}{2}, z = \frac{b + c - a}{2}$.

Thus, (3) is true.

We are done.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Comment: We consider an equilateral triangle as a simple form, we have:

$\Delta=\frac{abc}{4R}$

$a=b=c$

$R=\frac a{\sqrt 3}$

$ \Delta=\frac{\sqrt 3 a^2}{4}$

$$ \Delta^2=\frac{3a^4}{16}$$

Let $A=ab\cdot MN^2+bc\cdot NP^2+ca\cdot PM^2$

$$A=3 a^2\cdot(FG=\frac a 2)^2=\frac{3a^4}4$$

$\Rightarrow A=4\Delta^2$

In figure we see that:

$MN>\frac a 2\Rightarrow MN^2>\frac {a^2}4$

$NP>\frac b 2\Rightarrow NP^2>\frac {b^2}4$

$PM>\frac c 2\Rightarrow PM^2>\frac {c^2}4$

which deduce that :

$A=ab\cdot MN^2+bc\cdot NP^2+ca\cdot PM^2>4\Delta^2$